# Table contains particular value or not

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, linq, linq-to-sql

I am using linq to sql and my `Datatable(tbl_final_aut)` seems as

[image]

and I made a select query in my appliaction as

**.cs code**

```
var sel = db.selectdoc(24).ToList();

if (sel.Count == 3)
{
   //all doc are uploaded
}
else
{
   //  
}
```

on seeming my Datatable we can see that I will go in `if condition` but I want that if my `sel.count=2` or `sel.count=1` than I want to show that which groupname or type is not there in my datatable

`For example :`

if my datatable seems to be 
[image]

so my condition will go to else and there I want to get my alert box that other 2 groupname is not there like

```
var sel = db.selectdoc(24).ToList();

if (sel.Count == 3)
{
   //all doc are uploaded
}
else
{
   //I want in alert that "cover letter and CopyrightTra.. is not present"
}
```

**Store procedure code** is

```
 ALTER PROCEDURE dbo.selectdoc
 @art_aut_id int
AS
 select * from tbl_final_aut where art_aut_id=@art_aut_id
RETURN
```

As you see actually I have only `3 types` as you seen in my `1st datatable` that is `1,3,4`..I just want to know that if any one type says to be `3rd type is not` there or present in table than my `sel.count=2` so it will go in `else condition` and there I have to make some code which says that `type 3 or coverletter is required to be upload`.what code shall I make over there

error
[image]

datatype
[image]

Comment: What is `selectdoc` is it your stored procedure?

Comment: How do you know which group values should present in database table?

Comment: @SergeyBerezovskiy actually I have only 3 types as you seen in my 1st datatable that is 1,3,4..I just want to know that if any one type says to be 3 type is not there or present in table than it will go in else condition and there i have to make some code which says that type 3  or coverletter is required to be upload.what code shall i make over there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
string[] groupNames = { "Main Article", "Cover Letter" }; // list all groups

var missingGroups = 
    groupNames.Except(db.selectdoc(24).Select(d => d.groupname).Distinct());
```

You can also get all group names from database without hard-coding them in code:

```
string[] groupNames = db.tablename.Select(d => d.groupname).Distinct().ToArray();
```

Comment: i am sorry but if you take the groupName form the table as told then in missing groups what u will find?? nothing.. !! so you have to take the groupName either from another table or hardcoded.

Comment: you can use the **foreach loop for missingGroup** to display the message

Comment: @MiteshJain you can join missing groups in a string and assign it to label or show as alert `label.Text = String.Join(",", missingGroups);`

Comment: Hey it working, But here i have tried putting string[] groupNames = { "1", "3", "4" }; and at down code p.type instead p.groupname...but its showing error, what shall i have to do if i wanna right types

Comment: what to do if i want to write... string[] groupNames = { "1", "3", "4" }; var missingGroups =groupNames.Except(db.selectdoc(24).Select(d => d.type).Distinct());

Comment: @MiteshJain you should use values of appropriate type. If `type` is integer, then you should use integer value array `int[] types = { 1, 3, 4 };`

Comment: I am getting error on doing so..int[] types = { 1,3,4}; 
            var missingGroups =types.Except(db.selectdoc(24).Select(d => d.type).Distinct());

Comment: @MiteshJain always specify which exact error you get :) Otherwise people can't tell what went wrong

Comment: 'int[]' does not contain a definition for 'Except' and the best extension method overload 'System.Linq.Queryable.Except<TSource>(System.Linq.IQueryable<TSource>, System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<TSource>)' has some invalid arguments

Comment: @MiteshJain maybe `type` is nullable integer? Or it is decimal? Or byte? What exact type of `type` property?

Comment: its datatype is integer says to be int

Comment: @MiteshJain it's not possible. If `type` would be integer, then your code would work

Comment: SEE MY EDITED QUESTION I HAVE POSTED FIGURE OF DATATYPE AND ERROR PIC

Comment: @MiteshJain allowing nulls means that `type` column will be mapped to `Nullable<int>` property. So, you should use `int? []` array

Comment: @MiteshJain and it should not work for int - read my previous comment